# parsing CDATA (one more)

Tags: python, xml, cdata

I need to parse CDATA from the following svg-document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 2.4 -->
<svg height='28.692695pt' version='1.1' viewBox='-72.000004 -70.904267 60.575314 28.692695' width='60.575314pt' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>

<style type='text/css'>
<![CDATA[
text.f0 {font-family:cmex10;font-size:11.955168px}
text.f1 {font-family:cmmi12;font-size:11.955168px}
text.f2 {font-family:cmr12;font-size:11.955168px}
]]>
</style>
<g id='page1'>
<text class='f1' x='-72.000004' y='-53.569135'>c</text>
<text class='f2' x='-63.641186' y='-53.569135'>=</text>
<text class='f0' x='-51.215706' y='-70.426073'></text>
<text class='f1' x='-42.415333' y='-60.891712'>a<tspan x='-25.754955'>b</tspan>
<tspan x='-41.861851' y='-46.445899'>c</tspan>
<tspan x='-26.307752'>d</tspan>
</text>
<text class='f0' x='-20.225063' y='-70.426073'></text>
</g>
</svg>
```

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

file_svg= "my_path"

doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(file_svg)

style = doc.getElementsByTagName('style')

cdata = style[0].firstChild.wholeText
```

which gives me just the text inside CDATA like this (print cdata):

```
text.f0 {font-family:cmex10;font-size:11.955168px}
text.f1 {font-family:cmmi12;font-size:11.955168px}
text.f2 {font-family:cmr12;font-size:11.955168px}
```

But I need this text to be organized into smth like this:

```
{"f0":"cmex10","f1":"cmmi12","f2":"cmr12"}
```

I'm sure there is a way to extract the data in terms of text values: f0, f1, f2 and the values of font-families: cmex10, cmmi12, cmr12 with standard xml.dom.minidom operations.

I tried:

```
style[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

but it produced an empty string.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: The point of CDATA blocks is to be out of the scope of XML parsing. Try to find a regexp or other search technique in order to extract information out of CDATA and bring it to the format as you like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, CDATA should be parsed as text. Here is an example of simple parsing:

```
text = '''text.f0 {font-family:cmex10;font-size:11.955168px}
text.f1 {font-family:cmmi12;font-size:11.955168px}
text.f2 {font-family:cmr12;font-size:11.955168px}'''

d = {}

for line in text.split('\n'):
  value = line.split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
  key = line.split('.')[1].split(' ')[0]
  d[key] = value
  
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'f0': 'cmex10', 'f1': 'cmmi12', 'f2': 'cmr12'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below (using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html))

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 2.4 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="28.692695pt" version="1.1" viewBox="-72.000004 -70.904267 60.575314 28.692695" width="60.575314pt">
   <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[text.f0 {font-family:cmex10;font-size:11.955168px}
text.f1 {font-family:cmmi12;font-size:11.955168px}
text.f2 {font-family:cmr12;font-size:11.955168px}]]></style>
   <g id="page1">
      <text class="f1" x="-72.000004" y="-53.569135">c</text>
      <text class="f2" x="-63.641186" y="-53.569135">=</text>
      <text class="f0" x="-51.215706" y="-70.426073"></text>
      <text class="f1" x="-42.415333" y="-60.891712">
         a
         <tspan x="-25.754955">b</tspan>
         <tspan x="-41.861851" y="-46.445899">c</tspan>
         <tspan x="-26.307752">d</tspan>
      </text>
      <text class="f0" x="-20.225063" y="-70.426073"></text>
   </g>
</svg>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
style = root.find('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}style')
cdata_lines = style.text.split('\n')
data = {}
for line in cdata_lines:
  dot_idx = line.find('.') + 1
  space_idx = line.find(' ')
  f = line[dot_idx:space_idx]
  colon_idx = line.find(':') + 1
  other_idx = line.find(';')
  cmex = line[colon_idx:other_idx]
  data[f] = cmex
print(data)
```

output

```
{'f0': 'cmex10', 'f1': 'cmmi12', 'f2': 'cmr12'}
```